# How to inspect which api calls made with axios are still pending?

Tags: javascript, axios, frontend

I have long lived requests (few min or more), and I wanna see which call is in pending state from my code, so I don't trigger it again.

How can I see that?

Comment: You create an object where you store some unique id for each request when it starts and you remove it when the request is completed.

Comment: Ye, I guess that could be solved manually like that... I thought axios has some internal magic that will allow me to just hook into it and inspect pending requests...

Comment: it does not, as far as i know. You could use interceptors though to automate it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670782/know-if-there-are-pending-request-in-axios

Comment: If it had such internal magic you would be better off reading the docs and the source code.